# Bootstrap no me funciona text-align al pnerlo en la clase

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

> Estoy intentando poner en el centro la letra de la cabecera pero no lo consigo, ademas intento poner dos clases y no funcionan como pueden ser: color y align. No tengo idea de porque no me pilla ambas clases.

```
<p class="text-primary text-right" >Menu</p>
```

> , esa son las dos clases que no me pilla, y lo que quiero es que tenga un color determinado y ademas se centre

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Maquetado v.1</title>
</head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row bg-warning ">
            <!-- menu -->
            <p class="text-primary text-right" >Menu</p>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>fil-1 col-1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>fil-1 col2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>fil-1 col3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: quiero aclarar, por si hay lugar a dudas que el color si lo cambia, lo que no me esta haciendo es centrarlo en el div .Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que se centre debería ser asi:

```
<div class="row bg-warning ">
        <!-- menu -->
        <div class="col">
            <p class="text-primary text-center" >Menu</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Has la prueba. 
Nota: en cuanto al color a mi si me funciona, la clase text-primary en azul

Comment: Gracias Funciona, el truco era meterlo en el div no ?

Comment: Asi es, puesto que lo tenias dentro de un div.row